# Cypress Test Issue in debian

Tags: linux, cypress

I have installed Cypress in Debian. When I am trying to check its version or I am trying to execute any test cases then I am getting this error:

```
Command 'cypress' not found, did you mean:
  command 'cmpress' from deb infernal (1.1.4-1)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Comment: what do you get when you run it the way the docs say?

Answer (score -1):

downgrade the cypress by running npm install cypress@7.6.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).